# API Gateway Custom Domain Name getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created an api using AWS API Gateway and would like to attach a custom domain name to it. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ7IWmmkHKM&ab_channel=WornOffKeys) and have done the following:

1. Created new certificate on Certificate Manager (`mydomain.io` and `*.mydomain.io`)
2. Added CNAME to GoDaddy (since mine was purchased from Godaddy)
3. Set up a `api-dev.mydomain.io` on API gateway > Custom domain names, and mapped it to the API and dev stage in the "API Mappings".
4. On Route 53, added `api-dev.mydomain.io` as an A record and direct it to the API (the API domain name is correct) in step 3.

I believe that my setup should be correct to the best of my knowledge, and have waited 1 hour for it to "take effect".

I then write a simple script to test it but it throws the above error.

Code:

```
const axios = require("axios")

let baseUrl = "https://api-dev.mydomain.io"
let key = MY_API_KEY
let headers = {
    headers: {
        "x-api-key": key
    }
}

let usersEndpoint = baseUrl + '/token?email=someemail@gmail.com'

axios.get(usersEndpoint, headers)
.then(response => {
    let data = response.data
    console.log(data)
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Error message:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api-dev.mydomain.io
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'api-dev.mydomain.io',
  config: {
    url: 'https://api-dev.mydomain.io/token?email=someemail@gmail.com',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'x-api-key': MY_API_KEY,
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    ...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If your domain is managed by `GoDaddy` why do you use R53? Did you change name servers on `GoDaddy` to point to your HZ in R53?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for your response. No I did not. How do I do that?

Comment: The question is, do you want to manage your domain from R53 or keep using GoDaddy? There are many tutorias how to point GoDdday's name servers to R53, e.g. [here](https://www.radishlogic.com/aws/using-godaddy-domain-in-aws-route-53/).

Comment: @Marcin I believe I would prefer to use GoDaddy. The reason is because I am using my domain name on other cloud providers as well, such as Google Cloud. If I manage my domain from R53, I suppose that will cause some problems?

Comment: If you point to R53, then all subdomains will have to be managed there. If you want t use GoDaddy, then create `api-dev.mydomain.io` in GoDaddy, not in R53.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks. I created `api-dev.mydomain.io` on GoDaddy and it all works now. Happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Glad it works. Answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that `api-dev.mydomain.io` was created in Route 53, while it was managed by GoDaddy (name servers were not changed to Route 53).

The **solution** was to create `api-dev.mydomain.io` record in GoDaddy, rather then in Route 53.

Alternatively, to manage the domain in Route 53, one would have to updated name servers in GoDaddy to point to Route 53 Hosted Zone as explained in [Update the NS record with your current DNS service provider to use Route 53 name servers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html#migrate-dns-change-name-servers-with-provider).